# SecureUDID has anyone tested it extensively?

Tags: ios, udid

Due to the new Apple guidelines we are forced to remove UDID.
I've found the OpenUDID and SecureUDID solutions. OpenUDID fails in ios4.0+ so I went into SecureUDID (1.1 branch).

Does anyone else have commited apps with those two alternatives? Are they adequate to replace UDID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SecureUDID works and has shipped in many apps. Most recently, last night, it shipped with Path 2.1.1 using both Crashlytics and SecureUDID technology.

Hope that helps!